# MYSQL DELETING from Search result

Tags: php, mysql

I have an old DB with over 300k rows and I want to clean it up and only keep the new one, anyways I want to delete the rows which have the user_id of the results from the following query:

```
   SELECT user_id
   FROM wp_usermeta
   WHERE meta_value LIKE '%student%'
```

I have the needed user_id but they're in a column, so I used the following but it doesn't seem to be working

```
   DELETE FROM wp_usermeta 
   WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id
   FROM wp_usermeta
   WHERE meta_value LIKE '%student%')
```

So basically, how do I used the result's user_id to delete from the same Table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many rows, `IN` maybe works slow, you can use `JOIN` for deleting, like this:

`DELETE  wp_usermeta.*    FROM  wp_usermeta
INNER JOIN 
   ( SELECT user_id
       FROM wp_usermeta
       WHERE meta_value LIKE '%student%'
   ) t
ON
wp_usermeta.user_id = t.user_id`

Answer (score 3):

Why query the user id if you can just use the meta_value to delete the items?

```
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '%student%'
```

Comment: because there are actually more rows with the same user_id but not with meta_value having student

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `IN` operator for this search

Try something like

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 
WHERE user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM TABLE2 WHERE meta_value LIKE '%student%')
```

And If you have to search same table why not use the where condition directly

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE meta_value LIKE '%student%'
```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'wp_usermeta' for update in FROM clause

Comment: actually there are more rows with the same user_id but not with the meta_value having 'student'